# Analyzing Coded UI Tests Using Coded UI Test Logs

Tags: coded-ui-tests

i am trying to get the html log file for the coded ui tests.
i tried the steps mentioned in the following link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159363(v=vs.110).aspx

By default it generated .png file(image file) which captures only the screenshot of the active window where the error occurred.
So i tried using the other values for "EqtTraceLevel" in the configuration file, but there is no difference, it still generates image file.

Does it work for Windows application? if it does what are the additional settings required?

Answer (score 2):

To enable HTML logging in your tests you should add `Playback.PlaybackSettings.LoggerOverrideState = HtmlLoggerState.AllActionSnapshot;` to your test.

This will show all steps taken in your test and a corresponding screenshot of your application under test. It will also show you a highlight rectangle to show the found control.

Alternatively change `QTAgent32.exe.config` or `QTAgent32_40.exe.config` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE` (or where you have VS installed) to contain the following settings:

```
 <appSettings>
   <!--- Your settings -->
   <add key="EnableHtmlLogger" value="true"/>
 </appSettings>
```

And to increase the detail of your logging:

```
 <switches>
   <add name="EqtTraceLevel"value="4"/>
 </switches>
```

Where 0 is off, 1 for errors, 2 for warnings, 3 for info and 4 for verbose.