# How to disable taking screenshots while executing a C# coded ui project in debug mode

Tags: c#, .net, coded-ui-tests

In my C# console solution, I have a coded UI project. I make a startup project to test the UI coded project. While I run my startup project in debug mode, I notice that numerous screenshots are being added in the debug folder of the startup project. I have attached a screenshot about the Debug folder. I want to disable this.
 
Anybody, could you please help me on how I can disable this so that no screenshots can't be stored in the debug folder or anywhere else?

Thanks in advance.
NB.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise and .Net version is 4.6.1

Example Screenshot:

[image: example screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, you would recommend to read this [guide for Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify your question in order to help users to understand your problem.

Comment: I'd suggest that this is nothing to do with Visual Studio, and is more likely to be being done by whatever you are debugging, or something else that is already running on your machine.

Comment: @Richardissimo is right. For the sake of completeness, there should be a "TestResults" folder located at your "IonTest" project folder root.
You can read up about how to prevent this folder taking up to much disk space:
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmmitchmilam/archive/2013/04/21/visual-studio-tip-o-39-the-day-delete-your-test-results
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864721/mstest-how-to-limit-test-result-folders

Comment: @PixelPlex, Thank you very much for your such a brilliant idea. I will implement that.

Comment: @Richardissimo, screenshots are also being taken in the release build.

Comment: This does not surprise me, and I wouldn't be surprised if screenshots are also taken while Visual Studio is not running, and then you run your exe. But you haven't given us enough information to help you diagnose it. As Laura was trying to say, if you can give us a [mcve], then we might be able to help. You need to try to identify what causes the screenshots to appear. You may need to step through with a debugger to try to find what is causing the screenshots.

Comment: Yes, please provide us with what steps you already took to find out what is generating those screenshots. Things to get you started: I see your screenshots always have name format RPF*.png. Is this coincidence? Do you have any plugins, nuget packages, extension packages installed that could cause these screenshots to happen? etc...

Comment: I debug my project. Then, I noticed that the screenshot is being taken when an ui control is not found at the first sight. For example, when a method is called to launch a Windows Application, it's taking the screenshots as the application isn't open at this time. But if the application would be open already, it woudn't take any screenshot. This applies to all other controls like selecting a value from a combo box etc. If a combo value is already set, it doesn't take any screenshot, it takes screenshot when it has to select other value from the combo list.

Comment: Ahhh. They are coming from CodeUiTestBuilder. The only mention of which is the tag on the question, nothing else in the question or comments mentions it. It seems this is a common complaint and people have requested it be fixed here... https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/5831037-coded-ui-allow-user-to-disable-automatic-screens

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an `app.config` file in your project structure and add the following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <system.diagnostics>
  <switches>
   <add name="EqtTraceLevel" value="0" />
  </switches>
 </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

More readings here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/analyzing-coded-ui-tests-using-coded-ui-test-logs?view=vs-2017

From Thomas Bouman's [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943953/analyzing-coded-ui-tests-using-coded-ui-test-logs/29966507#29966507), the possible values for EqtTraceLevel: "0 is off, 1 for errors, 2 for warnings, 3 for info and 4 for verbose."